WordPress Contact Form 7 - Display Label and input field on the same line
I created a form using the Contact Form 7 plugin. I replaced the label with an image. Now I want to display the label and the input field on the same line.
I am getting this result:

Currently the form looks like this.
I want to achieve this design:

How can I achieve that?
I tried CSS modification but this didn't work for me.

We can't help sensibly without seeing the relevant code - you can find that in your browser's devtools inspect facility. And then show us what you have tried. 'CSS modification' doesn't tell us anything.

@Provibe Do not use images as a text of the input label, it may be take a time to load the images, instead use gradient text using CSS. Search for the gradient text and apply your text color to the background color which is gradient and use this css to achieve your design. .form-field {     display: flex;     align-items: center;     margin-bottom: 15px; }

Can try this:
<label class="custom-field" for="namefield">Your Name [text* your-name id:namefield]</label>

or if use below label:
<div class="form-field">
<label class="custom-field" for="namefield">Your Name</label>
[text* your-name id:namefield]
</div>

CSS:
.form-field {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


Try this in you css file:
.wpcf7-form p {
  display: flex;
}

